# How to get userAgent information in Selenium Web driver

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get user-agent information for browsers in selenium,java.I tried "HttpServletRequest "and find a method like as below.Which parameter should I give for "HttpServletRequest request"? is it url?

```
 private String getUserAgent(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader("user-agent");
    }
```

Also ,is there anyway to get user-agent in selenium like as javascript? Thanx.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
String userAgent = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return navigator.userAgent;");
```