# How to get user agent information in Selenium WebDriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the actual user agent that I am using in Selenium, at the moment with the `chromedriver`.

I found a Java version of this problem:
[How to get userAgent information in Selenium Web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229299/how-to-get-useragent-information-in-selenium-web-driver).

Does someone know how to do that in Python?

Comment: Visit http://www.whatsmyua.info/ with Selenium?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The same manner as inside your link:

```
user_agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
```

PS: Using `execute_script` method you can run JS inside your driver.

Hope it helps you!